# max uniform buffer size

Tags: webgl, webgl2

Consider the following glsl code:

```
layout (std140) uniform ubo_lights {
    mat4 a;
    mat4 b;
    mat4 c; // <-- results in error. removing or sticking to vec4 is ok
};
```

The error I get is:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION: It is undefined behaviour to use a uniform buffer that is too small.

On my current machine, [WebGl Report](https://webglreport.com/?v=2) shows:

```
Uniform Buffers
Max Uniform Buffer Bindings:    72
Max Uniform Block Size: 65536
Uniform Buffer Offset Alignment:    256
Max Combined Uniform Blocks:    32
Max Combined Vertex Uniform Components: 266240
Max Combined Fragment Uniform Components: 266240
```

Why am I hitting this limit? I would think there should be much more wiggle room than just 3 matrices!

For what it's worth, what I *really* want to do is something like this, e.g. to store 8 different lights:

```
#define MAX_LIGHTS 8

struct UboLight
{
    vec4 direction;
    vec4 color;
    vec4 position;
    vec4 extra;
};

layout (std140) uniform ubo_lights {
    UboLight lights[MAX_LIGHTS];
};
```

So any tips towards that goal are greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the implementation of whatever browser on whatever platform you're using.

Answer (score 1):

This is ultimately a bug of not uploading a large enough buffer to the ubo.

So, in the example above, the struct itself is 16 elements, and we have 8 instances, so the amount of data required is 128 values.

Uploading a too-small buffer results in the error here.

This can also happen by not being bound to the correct UBO when uploading (since the intended UBO will not have enough data supplied)

Here is a codepen showing the issue. e.g. comment out line 60 (supply less than the required data) to see the bug:

https://codepen.io/dakom/pen/wvXPqrE?editors=1010

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

```js
// not really drawing anything visible
const ubo = `
layout(std140) uniform foo_t {
    vec4 screen_and_position;
    vec4 color;
} foo;
`;

const vertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

${ubo}

void main() {
    vec2 screen = foo.screen_and_position.xy;
    vec2 pos = foo.screen_and_position.zw;
    float aspect = screen.y / screen.x;
    vec2 scale = vec2(aspect, 1);
    gl_Position = vec4(pos * scale, 0, 1);
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
`;

const fragmentShaderSource = `#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

${ubo}

void main() {
    color = foo.color;
}

`;

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
const program = compileProgram();

draw();

function draw() {
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  uploadBufferData();  
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
}

function uploadBufferData() {
  const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  // make sure to supply all the data!
  const data = Float32Array.from([
    canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0,
    // e.g. commenting out this line will fail
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
  ]);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, data, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  gl.bindBufferBase(gl.UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, buffer);
}
function compileProgram() {
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  
  const vShader = compileShader(program, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource);
  const fShader = compileShader(program, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource);
                   
  console.log("linking...");
  
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.error("error linking shader");
    console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  } else {
    console.log("linked shader :)");
  }
    
  return program;
}
function compileShader(program, shaderType, shaderSource) {
  const shaderName = shaderType === gl.VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment";
  const shader = gl.createShader(shaderType);
  
  console.log(`compiling ${shaderName}...`);
  
  gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.error(`Got compile error for ${shaderName}`);
    console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  } else {
    console.log(`compiled ${shaderName} :)`);
  }
    
  gl.attachShader(program,shader); 
  return shader;
}
```